# PDF parser not working in production environment

Tags: weblogic-10.x, flying-saucer

I have an application that generates some PDFs. That works in preproduction systems but not in production system. We deploy in weblogic 10.3.6, both environments are supposed to have the same configuration

We have received de OK to deploy a web-app after all functional test were made in a non productive environment. The issue is that the final PDF that the app has to create does not work in production (but in test environment, yes). 
We are using:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
            <artifactId>core-renderer</artifactId>
            <version>R8</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


public static void crearPDFHTML(String htmlPlantilla, OutputStream pdf)
    throws Exception {
        try
        {
            ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
            //String plantillaLimpia = makeTidy(htmlPlantilla);
            LOG.info("Antes de limpiar caracteres especiales");
            String limpio = quitarCaracteresEspeciales(htmlPlantilla);
            LOG.info("Antes de poner el documento en el render");
            LOG.info(limpio);
            renderer.setDocumentFromString(limpio);
            LOG.info("antes del layout");
            renderer.layout();//HERE FAILS IN PRODUCTIVE ENVIRONEMENT
            LOG.info("antes de crear PDF");
            renderer.createPDF(pdf);
            LOG.info("PDF creado con éxito");

        }catch(Throwable e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Exception(e);
    }
}
```

If the web app works fine in pre environement, it is supposed to work the same in pro environement, and generates the PDF.

stack trace:

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException 
        at es.msssi.gepsa.utils.PDFUtils.crearPDFHTML(PDFUtils.java:47) 
        at es.msssi.gepsa.utils.PlantillaPSA.rellenarPlantilla(PlantillaPSA.java:456) 
        at es.msssi.gepsa.web.controller.DocumentoPSAController.generaDocumentoPSA(DocumentoPSAController.java:269) 
        at es.msssi.gepsa.web.controller.PsaController.generaDocumentoPSA(PsaController.java:454) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) 
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215) 
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781) 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721) 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83) 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943) 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877) 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869) 
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) 
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:821) 
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227) 
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301) 
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:27) 
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:61) 
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:89) 
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) 
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:61) 
        at es.msssi.common.seguridad.GenericExisteAtributoFilter.doFilter(GenericExisteAtributoFilter.java:158) 
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:61) 
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119) 
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171) 
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71) 
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:61) 
        at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:163) 
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3714) 
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321) 
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2182) 
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1491) 
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221) 
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:459) 
        at weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpURLConnection.java:37) 
        at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1017) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.swing.NaiveUserAgent.resolveAndOpenStream(NaiveUserAgent.java:122) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextUserAgent.getImageResource(ITextUserAgent.java:54) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextReplacedElementFactory.createReplacedElement(ITextReplacedElementFactory.java:57) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.calcDimensions(BlockBox.java:674) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.calcDimensions(BlockBox.java:628) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:763) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:732) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.InlineBoxing.layoutInlineBlockContent(InlineBoxing.java:393) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.InlineBoxing.layoutContent(InlineBoxing.java:290) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layoutInlineChildren(BlockBox.java:938) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layoutChildren(BlockBox.java:919) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:802) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:732) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutBlockChild0(BlockBoxing.java:293) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutBlockChild(BlockBoxing.java:271) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutContent(BlockBoxing.java:89) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layoutChildren(BlockBox.java:922) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:802) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:732) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutBlockChild0(BlockBoxing.java:293) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutBlockChild(BlockBoxing.java:271) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutContent(BlockBoxing.java:89) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layoutChildren(BlockBox.java:922) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:802) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:732) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutBlockChild0(BlockBoxing.java:293) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutBlockChild(BlockBoxing.java:271) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutContent(BlockBoxing.java:89) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layoutChildren(BlockBox.java:922) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:802) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:732) 
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.layout(ITextRenderer.java:209) 
        at es.msssi.gepsa.utils.PDFUtils.crearPDFHTML(PDFUtils.java:37) 
        at es.msssi.gepsa.utils.PlantillaPSA.rellenarPlantilla(PlantillaPSA.java:456) 
        at es.msssi.gepsa.web.controller.DocumentoPSAController.generaDocumentoPSA(DocumentoPSAController.java:269) 
        at es.msssi.gepsa.web.controller.PsaController.generaDocumentoPSA(PsaController.java:454) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) 
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215) 
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781) 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721) 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83) 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943) 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877) 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868) 
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) 
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820) 
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227) 
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125) 
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301) 
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26) 
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60) 
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) 
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) 
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60) 
        at es.msssi.common.seguridad.GenericExisteAtributoFilter.doFilter(GenericExisteAtributoFilter.java:158) 
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60) 
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119) 
        at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:324) 
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460) 
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103) 
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171) 
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71) 
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60) 
        at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:163) 
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60) 
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3748) 
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3714) 
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321) 
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120) 
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2283) 
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2182) 
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1491) 
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:263) 
        ... 1 more
```

Comment: Try to give more information: Do you get some error messages in production? What are the logs saying? What exactly is the problem? The PDFs are not generated or they are generated but can't be opened? Should we guess further?

Comment: Ah an I forget to answer your questions: No they don't have the same configuration because if they had, it would work...

Comment: The error is just null pointer exception in the line I have put (renderer.layout()). It seems "something" failing when trying to fit the html template to page configuration. I have tried to search if weblogic 10.3.6 has some issue with page configurations, with no result. The PDFs are not generated. I'll try to explain the steps a bit better:
1) take data base information to make the PDF---> OK
2) fill the html template with that information---> OK
3) transform template to page layout -->NOK (null pointer exception calling layout)

Comment: Ok but there is till too much missing. You say there is a NPE in that line. So the renderer is null? Or is the exception thrown within the layout method? Just post your stacktrace here. And how do you set/intitialize your renderer? That code part is missing... Sorry but with this little information we cannot help

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer and patient. I have added the stack trace in main issue. Renderer is not null, as renderer.setDocument() works fine, the NPE is thrown in layout method, the renderer is initialized just calling the dafault constructor. As I said, same code works locally, works in PRE. I wonder that it could be an issue with a library provided by the server, but I cannot be more accurate.... Thanks a lot for yor time

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally the issue was solved. It's a quite strange situation, and I don't think this will help anyone, but....

The issue is that in DES and PRE (non- productive environements) you can take the images the PDF needs using two urls (http or https) and works with both well. But in PRO the security configuration does not allow Itext to ask for a image using http. It must use https

So that was all, just change URL configuration, the PDF works and all people is happy again.

Thanks for the answers and patience